# Add ylab to ggplot with fivethirtyeight ggtheme

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a label to the y axis if you are using `theme_fivethirtyeight`? I tried `ylab` but it does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Cars")
p2 + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_fivethirtyeight("cyl") +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + ylab('SOMETHING')
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can, but it'll take a bit more work than `ylab` because you need to change some of the `theme` settings that are the defaults in `theme_fivethirtyeight`.  If you take a look at the code for `theme_fivethirtyeight` (just run `theme_fivethirtyeight` in your console to see the code), you'll see that `axis.title` is set to `element_blank()`.  So this theme has no axis titles at all.  You'll need to change this if you want to set a y axis label.

For example, you could add

```
theme(axis.title = element_text()) + ylab('Something')
```

to your graph, but then you'll get an x axis label, as well.

An alternative would be to use

```
theme(axis.title = element_text(), axis.title.x = element_blank()) + ylab('Something')
```

[image]

As`axis.title.y` inherits from `axis.title`, it didn't work to just set `axis.title.y` to `element_text()`.

Comment: Or to set globally, use something like `theme_update(axis.title = element_text())` (after setting the theme globally using `theme_set`) to enable both x and y labels.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same issue with theme_excel_new(), which is also from the ggthemes library.