# X and Y Labels Not Appearing on my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels

I am able to add titles to my graph but the x and y labels do not show up. Instead I get a legend for count on the bottom.

```
    pl <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating))

    pl2 <- pl + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, aes(fill = ..count..))
    pl2
    pl3 <- pl2  + xlab('Movie Rating') + ylab('Count')
    pl3
    pl3 + ggtitle('MY TITLE')
```

Here is an imgur link to the graph:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp))`, I cannot reproduce this problem. I'm using ggplot2-3.2.0 on R=3.5.3, what versions are you using?

Comment: Please include all the libraries you're using in the question. I was able to recognise the look of the plot so I can guess which library you're using (`ggthemes`), and therefore the issue, which is specific to this theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight()` as your `ggplot` theme. This theme has the axis labels set not to appear by default. You can turn them back on with `theme(axis.title = element_text())`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
theme_set(theme_fivethirtyeight())

pl <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, aes(fill = ..count..)) + 
    xlab('Movie Rating') + 
    ylab('Count') + 
    ggtitle('MY TITLE')
# Current plot, no labels
pl

# Turn the labels on
pl +
    theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

Comment: Hehe, good find ... if this is it, DannyBrown, might I suggest that when you provide a minimal working example (mostly good job, thanks, but we need data too), the MWE should be used on your end to produce the graphic that you allege is from that code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solution. I will also provide more data and information next time when I post a question, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered here:
[Add ylab to ggplot with fivethirtyeight ggtheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181990/add-ylab-to-ggplot-with-fivethirtyeight-ggtheme)

For completeness, here is [aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith)'s answer:

You can, but it'll take a bit more work than `ylab` because you need to change some of the `theme` settings that are the defaults in `theme_fivethirtyeight`. If you take a look at the code for `theme_fivethirtyeight` (just run `theme_fivethirtyeight` in your console to see the code), you'll see that `axis.title` is set to `element_blank()`. So this theme has no axis titles at all. You'll need to change this if you want to set a y axis label.

For example, you could add

```r
theme(axis.title = element_text()) + ylab('Something')
```

to your graph, but then you'll get an x axis label, as well.

An alternative would be to use

```r
theme(axis.title = element_text(), axis.title.x = element_blank()) + ylab('Something')
```

As `axis.title.y` inherits from `axis.title`, it didn't work to just set `axis.title.y` to `element_text()`.